# Sublime Text 2: Cannot override the global file_exclude_pattern?

Tags: sublimetext2

Is it possible to include a file in per-project settings that's been excluded by Sublime Text's global settings?

For example, the global settings have mandated that "*.obj" files (intending files output by a build process) be excluded. Without changing those global settings, I cannot seem to include .obj files (these being 3d model files) in my project. Putting `file_exclude_patterns` in the "settings" section doesn't override, and adding a `file_include_patterns` key to the paths section simply filters every other file type out, and yet the .obj files *still* aren't included! (Apparently exclusion filters are applied after inclusion filters.)

So do I have to change global settings for this then??

Answer (score 2):

I just came across exactly the same problem for exactly the same files.

The only solution seems to be to override the setting in your user settings, minus the "*.obj" wildcard.  If you need to exclude those files in other projects or folders within projects, you'll have to specify the setting in your project settings.